# How does blender convert a color's value to a numeric value?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, color

I've been creating procedural materials in cycles likewise creating roughness textures but recently something's been bothering me. The Value showed in the HSV do not match with an actual numeric value, thus creating unexpected results.
In my current scene I have a gray color which has 0.5 as Value in the HSV sliders, but then if I connect that into roughness or any other slot that needs values I get a different result than if I input a value node with 0.5 as value (hopefully this paragraph made sense). So my question here would be, how to treat colored textures (roughness for instance) in order to get the correct output values (or at least the desired ones), meaning that if I have a texture with HSV showing 0.5, the actual value be 0.5.
Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A math value of 0.5 is like assigning RGB values of 0.5 each, which is a HSV value of 0.735.
I don't know the logic underneath this choice, I think it's about linear and logarithmic perception of light.

Comment: I didn't now RGB was the way to go for values, thanks a lot!